# ggplot discarding some breaks when using user-defined transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, transformation

I have my own transformation for the y axis which I want to use in ggplot:

```
library(scales)

disc<-trans_new("disc",
            function(y) {y*{y<10 & y>=0}+((y-10)/3+10)*{y>=10 & y<16}+((y-16)/4.5+12)*{y>=16 & y<25}+
                ((y-25)/7.5+14)*{y>=25 & y<40}+((y-40)/11.5+16)*{y>=40}},
            function(x) {x*{x<10 & x>=0}+((x-10)*3+10)*{x>=10 & x<16}+((x-12)*4.5+16)*{x>=16 & x<25}+
                ((x-14)*7.5+25)*{x>=25 & x<40}+((x-16)*11.5+40)*{x>=40}},
            domain=c(0,Inf)
```

This may look odd, but the principle is quite simple: interval [0,10] stays as itself but [10, 16], is 'shrinked' to [10, 12], [16, 25] to [12, 14], ... and [40, 63] to [18, 20]. (You may consider this as a bad habit like cutting the axis but it's not the point and I'm doing this anyway.)

But when I draw a plot using this transformation, the last break (63), or the tick mark at least, is missing:

```
library(ggplot2)

df<-data.frame(x=10,y=10)

ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y)) +
   scale_y_continuous(trans=disc,
                 limits=c(0,100),
                 breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,16,25,40,63),
                 label=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,16,25,40,63))
```

[image]

When I tried different breaks I noticed that replacing 63 with 56 worked but 57 and higher disappeared. I checked my transformation multiple times, but it seems fine. I even tried to add new 'slots' like this

```
disc<-trans_new("disc",
            function(y) {y*{y<10 & y>=0}+((y-10)/3+10)*{y>=10 & y<16}+((y-16)/4.5+12)*{y>=16 & y<25}+
                ((y-25)/7.5+14)*{y>=25 & y<40}+((y-40)/11.5+16)*{y>=40 & y<63}+((y-63)/13.5+18)*{y>=63 & y<100}+
                ((y-100)/15.5+20)*{y>=100}},
            function(x) {x*{x<10 & x>=0}+((x-10)*3+10)*{x>=10 & x<16}+((x-12)*4.5+16)*{x>=16 & x<25}+
                ((x-14)*7.5+25)*{x>=25 & x<40}+((x-16)*11.5+40)*{x>=40 &x<63}+((x-63)/13.5+18)*{x>=63 & x<100}+
                ((x-20)*15.5+100)*{x>=100}},
            domain=c(0,Inf))
```

with no effect. So, what goes wrong? I'm using R version 3.6.0 and haven't tried with any other version or computer.

Comment: Your inverse isn't the inverse of the transformation `disc$inverse(disc$transform(1:60))` should return `1:60`, but after 16 something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your third argument to `trans_new()` should be the inverse of the second, so your call would be:

```
disc<-trans_new("disc",
                function(y) {y*{y<10 & y>=0}+((y-10)/3+10)*{y>=10 & y<16}+((y-16)/4.5+12)*{y>=16 & y<25}+
                    ((y-25)/7.5+14)*{y>=25 & y<40}+((y-40)/11.5+16)*{y>=40}},
                function(x) {x*{x<10 & x>=0}+((x-10)*3+10)*{x>=10 & x<12}+((x-12)*4.5+16)*{x>=12 & x<14}+
                    ((x-14)*7.5+25)*{x>=14 & x<16}+((x-16)*11.5+40)*{x>=16}},
                domain=c(0,Inf))
```

then `disc$inverse(disc$transform(1:63))` gives `1:63` as expected, and the breaks appear correctly.

[image]